# Lambda@edge function using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

We are trying to write a lambda@edge function to trigger on `viewer-request`. I was able to find lots of examples on using JavaScript.

e.g

```
'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('Event: ', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));
    console.log('Context: ', JSON.stringify(context, null, 2));
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

    // You can also store and read the redirect map
    // in DynamoDB or S3, for example.
    const redirects = {
        '/r/music':    '/card/bcbd2481',
        '/r/tree':     '/card/da8398f4',
    };

    if (redirects[request.uri]) {
        return callback(null, {
            status: '302',
            statusDescription: 'Found',
            headers: {
                'location': [{ 
                    key: 'Location',
                    value: redirects[request.uri] }]
            }
        });
    }

    callback(null, request);
};
```

The above code will redirect requests that matches a specific path. Can anyone advice on how to port a similiar code to python? or share resources/information on deploying python lambda@edge functions.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Lambda@Edge *formerly* allowed only Node.js, so at the time this question was initially asked, it was not possible to create Lambda@Edge functions in Python, or any other language besides Node.js (or inside a Node.js wrapper).

<strike>Lambda@Edge supports only the Node.js 6.10 and 8.10 runtime environments as of August, 2018.</strike>

Lambda@Edge now supports Node.js 8.10, Node.js 10.x, and [Python 3.7](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/lambdaedge-adds-support-for-python-37/), as of August, 2019.

The edge environment is notably different than the general Lambda offering in a number of ways: see [Lambda Function Configuration and Execution Environment](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-requirements-limits.html#lambda-requirements-lambda-function-configuration) in the CloudFront Developer Guide.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, [Lambda@Edge adds support for Python 3.7](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/08/lambdaedge-adds-support-for-python-37/).